# Simplest svg code needed to fill viewport

Tags: xml, svg

My **goal** is to have a **`.svg`** file that fills the entire viewport.

#### [This icon.svg](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryanve/wtb/v0.1.0/icon.svg) seems to work

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>Chocolate</title>
  <rect fill="Chocolate" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

#### Questions

- What is the simplest code necessary to do this with cross-browser compatibility?
- `rect` or another way?
- doctype? attributes?

Comment: Github's previewer seems not to support SVG files. You could raise it as a github issue I guess.

Comment: My github previews svg fine start tag <svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1960' height='1358' viewBox='0 0 1960 1358'>. Could it be version number?

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner works with the current versions of Chrome, Firefox, and MS Edge

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color: chocolate;"><title>Chocolate</title></svg>
```

Specific versions:

- Chrome 81.0.4044.129
- Firefox 75.0
- MS Edge 44.17763.831.0